# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, frameworks, entity

With ASP .NET MVC3.

In my controller I have this portion of code

```
    MasterMindDnetEntities context = new MasterMindDnetEntities();
    List<MasterMindDnet.Games> Games = (from g in context.Games
                                        join u in context.Users on g.g_u_Id equals u.u_Id
                                        where u.u_Login == User.Identity.Name
                                        select g).ToList();
    @ViewBag.Games = Games;
    @ViewBag.GameCount = Games.Count;
    return View("Index");
```

In the controll, Games works fine as a list.

In my view I have:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.GameCount; i++)
{
    ViewBag.Games = ViewBag.Games[i];
```

At line `ViewBag.Games = ViewBag.Games[i];`, I get the exception :

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.

In a previous version I had `i < ViewBag.Games.Count;` instead of `i < ViewBag.GameCount;` and it said that `ViewBag.Games` does not have  a definition for `Count`.

How could I solve this ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem of dynamic proxies mean that you have to declare "statically" what's in your ViewBag.

So in your View, just make :

```
@{
    List<MasterMindDnetGames> games = ViewBag.Games;

    for (var i = 0; i < games.Count; i++) {
       var game = games[i];//declare it in the scope you need
       //bla bla bla
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried your solution and it works fine. But I had already found another thing to make this work: replacing the for by a foreach, as in this case I don't really need the i varaible.